# vb.net xls to csv with quotes?

Tags: vb.net, excel, ms-access, csv, xls

I have a xls file, or a csv without quotes, and using vb.net need to turn it into a csv with quotes around every cell. If I open the xls/csv without quotes in MS Access, set every column to text and then export it, its in the format I need. Is there an easier way? If not, how do I do replicate this in vb.net? Thanks.

Comment: can you give an example of the data?

Comment: "1","2","3","4" is what I need, instead of 1,2,3,4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [.Net OLE DB provider](http://connectionstrings.com/textfile#p20), you can specify the .csv formatting details in a schema.ini file in the folder your data files live in. For the 'unquoted' .csv the specs
should look like

```
[noquotes.csv]        <-- file name
ColNameHeader=True    <-- or False
CharacterSet=1252     <-- your encoding
Format=Delimited(,)   <-- 
TextDelimiter=        <-- important: no " in source file
Col1=VendorID Integer <-- your columns, of course
Col2=AccountNumber Char Width 15
```

for the 'quoted' .csv, just change the name and delete the TextDelimiter= line (put quotes around text fields is the default).

Then connect to the Text Database and execute the statement

```
SELECT * INTO [quotes.csv] FROM [noquotes.csv]
```

(as this creates quotes.csv, you may want to delete the file before each experimental run)

Added to deal with "Empty fields must be quoted"

This is a VBScript demo, but as the important things are the parameters for .GetString(), you'll can port it to VB easily:

```
    Dim sDir   : sDir       = resolvePath( "§LibDir§testdata\txt" )
    Dim sSrc   : sSrc       = "noquotes.csv"
    Dim sSQL   : sSQL       = "SELECT * FROM [" & sSrc & "]"
    Dim oTxtDb : Set oTxtDb = New cADBC.openDb( Array( "jettxt", sDir ) )
    WScript.Echo goFS.OpenTextFile( goFS.BuildPath( sDir, sSrc ) ).ReadAll()
    Dim sAll : sAll = oTxtDb.GetSelectFRO( sSQL ).GetString( _
                             adClipString, , """,""", """" & vbCrlf & """", "" _
                      )
    WScript.Echo   """" & Left( sAll, Len( sAll ) - 1 )
```

and output:

```
    VendorID;AccountNumber;SomethingElse
    1;ABC 123 QQQ;1,2
    2;IJK 654 ZZZ;2,3
    3;;3,4

    "1","ABC 123 QQQ","1,2"
    "2","IJK 654 ZZZ","2,3"
    "3","","3,4"
```

(german locale, therefore field separator ; and decimal symbol ,)

Same output from this VB.Net code:

```
    Imports ADODB
    ...

        Sub useGetString()
            Console.WriteLine("useGetString")

            Const adClipString As Integer = 2
            Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
            Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
            Dim sAll As String

            cn.ConnectionString = _
                 "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
               & "Data Source=M:\lib\kurs0705\testdata\txt\;" _
               & "Extended Properties=""text;"""

            cn.Open()
            rs = cn.Execute("SELECT * FROM [noquotes.csv]") 
            sAll = rs.GetString( adClipString, , """,""", """" & vbCrLf & """", "" )
            cn.Close()
            sAll = """" & Left( sAll, Len( sAll ) - 1 )
            Console.WriteLine( sAll )
        End Sub
```

Comment: This sounds awesome, I will give this a try.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without specifying every column? I'd like to make it more generic so it will be able to convert any csv file.

Comment: If you don't specify the columns, the driver will guess the type and possibly (not) quote fields you want (not) quoted. If that's a problem, you could programmatically edit the schema.ini file before you execute the "SELECT INTO" statement.

Comment: Grabbed the number of columns when the csv file is generated and made a loop to add all the columns as text, works beautifully. Thanks so much.

Comment: Is there any way to make blank cells have quotes as well?

Comment: I don't think so; I found statements like "empty fields may be enclosed in quotes", my drivers didn't do it, and I don't remember a schema.ini property for this purpose. But that's surely not conclusive. If this is fatal for your project, and you want to quote all fields, using the ADO GetString method creatively may be a way to do the conversion without loopings.

Comment: Unfortunately it is critical. I'm looking at the ADO GetString method and don't quite see how I could make it work without pulling the file into a string and then looping through it and converting? Or is that what you meant?

Comment: I'm trying to convert it to vb.net. What is are oTxtDB, cADBC and goFS, and sAll?

Comment: cADBC is a wrapper class for ADODB.Connection, oTxtDB is an instance of that class (the connection); goFS is a FileSystemObject used for IO operations; sALL is the result of applying .GetString to the recordset. Concentrate on the params for .GetString: the field separator is set to '","' and the record separator to '"\r\n"'. Then we just have to add the first " and to cut off the spurious last " to get all fields quoted.

Comment: @Shawn: without seeing your code (and probably your data) I can't help you. Any suggestion how we could cooperate in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the method at [this link](http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/141.html).
What you can do to make sure quotes go around is append quotes to the beginning and end of each column data in the loop that is putting the column data in the file.

for example make the loop like this:

```
For InnerCount = 0 To ColumnCount - 1
    Str &= """" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(OuterCount).Item(InnerCount) & ""","
Next
```

Comment: That would work. I'd like to see if there are any other solutions as everytime I've had to work inside an excel file via vb.net its been very slow.

Comment: As I proposed a different solution, I'm probably biased. But a person considering this approach should ponder 3 questions: Do you want (1) to quote all field values regardless of type? (2) a trailing , in each row? (3) to use string concatenation in a 2. level loop in a language with immutable strings?

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Those are very valid questions to think about.

Answer (score -1):

```
Public Class clsTest

Public Sub Test
Dim s as string = "C:\!Data\Test1.csv"

        Dim Contents As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(s)


        Dim aryLines As String() = Contents.Split(New String() { Environment.Newline }, StringSplitOptions.None)
        Dim aryParts() As String
        Dim aryHeader() As String
        Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable 
        For i As Integer = 0 To aryLines.Length - 1
            aryParts = SplitCSVLine(aryLines(i))
            If dt Is Nothing And aryHeader Is Nothing Then 
                aryHeader = CType(aryParts.Clone, String())
            ElseIf dt Is Nothing And aryHeader IsNot Nothing Then
                dt = DTFromStringArray(aryParts, 1000, "", aryHeader)
            Else
                DTAddStringArray(dt, aryParts)
            End If
        Next
        dt.dump
End Sub 

Public Shared Function SplitCSVLine(strCSVQuotedLine As String) As String()
        Dim aryLines As String() = strCSVQuotedLine.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
        Dim aryParts As String() = Nothing
        For i As Integer = 0 To aryLines.Length - 1
            Dim regx As New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(",(?=(?:[^\""]*\""[^\""]*\"")*(?![^\""]*\""))")
            aryParts = regx.Split(aryLines(i))
            For p As Integer = 0 To aryParts.Length - 1
                aryParts(p) = aryParts(p).Trim(" "c, """"c)
            Next
        Next
        Return aryParts
End Function

Public Shared Function DTFromStringArray(ByVal aryValues() As String, Optional ByVal intDefaultColumnWidth As Integer = 255, Optional ByVal strTableName As String = "tblArray", Optional ByVal aryColumnNames() As String = Nothing) As DataTable
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strTableName) Then strTableName = "tblArray"
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable(strTableName)
        Dim colNew(aryValues.GetUpperBound(0)) As DataColumn
        If aryColumnNames Is Nothing Then
            ReDim aryColumnNames(aryValues.Length)
        Else
            If aryColumnNames.GetUpperBound(0) < aryValues.GetUpperBound(0) Then
                ReDim Preserve aryColumnNames(aryValues.Length)
            End If
        End If
        For x As Integer = aryColumnNames.GetLowerBound(0) To aryColumnNames.GetUpperBound(0)
            If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aryColumnNames(x)) Then
                aryColumnNames(x) = "Field" & x.ToString
            Else
                aryColumnNames(x) = aryColumnNames(x)
            End If
        Next
        For i As Integer = 0 To aryValues.GetUpperBound(0)
            colNew(i) = New DataColumn
            With colNew(i)
                .ColumnName = aryColumnNames(i) '"Value " & i
                .DataType = GetType(String)
                .AllowDBNull = False
                .DefaultValue = ""
                .MaxLength = intDefaultColumnWidth
                .Unique = False
            End With
        Next
        dt.Columns.AddRange(colNew)
        Dim pRow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
        For i As Integer = aryValues.GetLowerBound(0) To aryValues.GetUpperBound(0)
            pRow.Item(i) = aryValues(i)
        Next
        dt.Rows.Add(pRow)
        Return dt
End Function

Public Shared Sub DTAddStringArray(ByRef dt As DataTable, ByVal aryRowValues() As String)
        Dim pRow As DataRow
        pRow = dt.NewRow
        For i As Integer = aryRowValues.GetLowerBound(0) To aryRowValues.GetUpperBound(0)
            pRow.Item(i) = aryRowValues(i)
        Next
        dt.Rows.Add(pRow)
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation of what you are doing and how it answers OP's question.